# Inverting a rather complex set of regexes

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm sort of new to regular expressions, and none of the solutions I found online helped/worked.

I'm dealing with a one-line String in JavaScript, it'll contain five types of data mixed in.

- A "#" followed by six numbers/letters (HTML color) (`/#....../g`)
- A forward slash followed by any of a few specific characters (`/\/(\+|\^|\-|#|!\+|_|@|\*|%|&|~)/g`)
- A "$" followed by a sequence of letters and a "|" (`/\$([^\|]+)/g`)
- A "|" alone (`/\|/g`)
- **Alphanumeric characters that do not fall under any of these categories**

The thing is, I have regexes to match the first four categories, that are important.
The problem is that I need a single Regex that I'll use to replace all the characters that DO NOT match for the first four regexes with a single character, such as "§".

Example:

`This#00CC00 is green$Courier| and /^mono|spaced`

`§§§§#00CC00§§§§§§§§§$Courier|§§§§§/^§§§§|§§§§§§`

I know I may be attacking this problem the wrong way, I'm rather new to regular expressions.
Essentially, how do I make a regex that means "anything that doesn't have any matches for regexes x, y, or z"?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So if your string was: `"#1234567"` it should be changed to: `"#123456§"`?

Comment: Yes, I wany everything that doesn't match the four regexes to be replaced. Testing the regex `/#......|\/(\+|\^|\-|#|!\+|_|@|\*|%|&|~)|\$([^\|]+)\||\|/g` on [this site](http://www.regexr.com/) shows exactly what I mean. I want everything that is selected to be not selected and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this pattern

```
((#\w{6}|\/[\/\(\+\^\-]|\$\w+\||\|)*).
```

and replace w/ `$1§`
Downside is your preserved pattern has to be followed by at least one character
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/128)

```
(                   # Capturing Group (1)
  (                 # Capturing Group (2)
    #               # "#"
    \w              # <ASCII letter, digit or underscore>
    {6}             # (repeated {6} times)
    |               # OR
    \/              # "/"
    [\/\(\+\^\-]    # Character Class [\/\(\+\^\-]
    |               # OR
    \$              # "$"
    \w              # <ASCII letter, digit or underscore>
    +               # (one or more)(greedy)
    \|              # "|"
    |               # OR
    \|              # "|"
  )                 # End of Capturing Group (2)
  *                 # (zero or more)(greedy)
)                   # End of Capturing Group (1)
.                   # Any character except line break
```

Code copied from Regex101

```
var re = /((#\w{6}|\/[\/\(\+\^\-]|\$\w+\||\|)*)./gm;   
var str = 'This#00CC00 is green$Courier| and /^mono|spaced|\n';  
var subst = '$1§';   
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: The regex seems to work on the link you provided, yes. Now, this may sound dumb, but how do I make such a replacement using JavaScript?

Comment: Had to make a small change, to `/((#\w{6}|\/[\/\(\+\^\-]|\$.+\||\|)*)./gm`. Other than that, works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoPaschoalinoto, you may want to change it to `/((#\w{6}|\/[\/\(\+\^\-]|\$.+?\||\|)*)./gm`, note the lazy operator `?`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as efficient as a working regular expression but it works. Basically it gets all of the matches and fills the parts between with `§` characters. One nice thing is you don't have to be a regular expression genius to update it, so hopefully more people can use it.

```
var str = 'This#00CC00 is green$Courier| and /^mono|spaced';
var patt=/#(\d|\w){6}|\/(\+|\^|\-|#|!\+|_|@|\*|%|&|~)|\$([^\|]+)\||\|/g;
var ret = "";

pos = [];
while (match=patt.exec(str)) {
    pos.push(match.index);
    pos.push(patt.lastIndex);
    console.log(match.index + ' ' + patt.lastIndex);
}

for (var i=0; i<pos.length; i+=2) {
    ret += Array(1+pos[i]- (i==0 ? 0 : pos[i-1])).join("§");
    ret += str.substring(pos[i], pos[i+1]);
}
ret += Array(1+str.length-pos[pos.length-1]).join("§");

document.body.innerHTML = str +"<br>"+ret;

console.log(str);
console.log(ret);
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/c18puq3h/)